# HTML5 as default in DoubleClick for publisher small business

Tags: html, google-dfp

I just want to ask how to make HTML5 the default instead of Flash ads in  a Google DFP small business. I saw in some articles that I could add `displayHTML5=true` but I am not sure where to put it.

Here is my code:

```
<script src='http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'>
googletag.pubads()
.definePassback('10822449/300x250-RR1', [[300,250]])
.setTargeting('categories',['adsamples01'])
.display();
```

I tried adding `(displayHTML5=true)` to key-value in the inventory and adding the code below to the above script

```
.setTargeting('displayHTML5',['true'])
```

...but it did not work.